# How to remove comments in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have known that I can use //, /* */, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to comment many lines in C#, I want to know whether there is any way to remove it fastest? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Is it Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

use shortcut keys,

Comment = (Ctr+K, C)
UnComment = (Ctr+K, U)

This is work above 2010